# Porque a minha app fecha quando clico em algum botão?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, kotlin

Estou a começar em mobile, e aparece me este erro quando pressiono em qualquer botão, abaixo o erro que aparece.

Log Cat

```
Process: com.example.estevaidar, PID: 3999
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onButtonClicked_Continuar(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'continuar_button'
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:479)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:437)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
            at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

*
```

XML

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#43A649"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_scan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textBem_Vindo"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:text="@string/title_bemvindo"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="48sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Gestor_Ativos"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:text="@string/title_gestordeativos"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"

            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_email"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:text="@string/title_email"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_entry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/hintemail"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pass"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"


            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:text="@string/title_pass"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_entry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/hintpassword" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxLOGIN"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

            android:buttonTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:checked="false"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:text="@string/checkbox"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continuar_button"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"

            android:background="@color/branco_menu"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked_Continuar"
            android:text="@string/button_continuar"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"

            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registar_button"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"

            android:background="#97cf9a"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked_Registar"
            android:text="@string/button_registar"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"

            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Java

package com.example.estevaidar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBoxLOGIN) {
        if (checked) {
            // Se a checkbox estiver "TRUE"

        } else {
            // Se a checkbox estiver "FALSE"

        }
    }
}

public void onButtonClicked_Continuar() {
    Button continuar_button = findViewById(R.id.continuar_button);
    continuar_button.setOnClickListener(v -> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main));
}

public void onButtonClicked_Registar() {
    Button register_button = findViewById(R.id.registar_button);
    register_button.setOnClickListener(v -> setContentView(R.layout.activity_singin));

}
```

}

Manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScannedMaterialActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".FornecedorActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MaterialActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Normalmente isso pode ser erro em tempo de execução, por exemplo, passar uma string em um lugar que esperava um número ou coisas do tipo. também alguma função pode estar recebendo um undefined de alguém.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá.
O problema acontece pois você não declarou seus métodos no método **Parent**, que nesse caso é o ***onCreate***, portanto, ele não pode ser encontrado e chamado pelo XML.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    onButtonClicked_Continuar();
    onButtonClicked_Registar();
    
}
```

Leve em consideração que uma prática melhor é não definir o "onClick" no XML, e sim definir os componentes de maneira separada e organizada na sua Activity/Fragment, tendo isso em mente, remova o onClick dos seus botões no XML e seu código deveria estar assim (ou parecido com isso):

```
package com.example.estevaidar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
    Button continuarButton;
    Button registrarButton;
    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        
        continuarButton = findViewById(R.id.continuar_button);
        registrarButton = findViewById(R.id.registar_button);
        
        
        configuraBotaoContinuar();
        configuraBotaoRegistrar();

    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        // Is the view now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBoxLOGIN) {
            if (checked) {
                // Se a checkbox estiver "TRUE"

            } else {
                // Se a checkbox estiver "FALSE"

            }
        }
    }

    public void configuraBotaoContinuar() {
        continuarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        });
    }

    public void configuraBotaoRegistrar() {
                registrarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_singin));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -2):

```
public void onButtonClicked_Continuar(View view) {
    Button continuar_button = view.findViewById(R.id.continuar_button);
    continuar_button.setOnClickListener(v -> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main));
}

public void onButtonClicked_Registar(View view) {
    Button register_button = view.findViewById(R.id.registar_button);
    register_button.setOnClickListener(v -> setContentView(R.layout.activity_singin));

}
```

Tente assim

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).